# Joining multiple relationships from separate tables into one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have several models that are relevant to this question..

- UserGroupPermission
- UserGroup
- User
- UserPermission
- Permission

Essentially, A User can be assigned a permission through either their UserGroup or directly. UserGroups are tied to specific permissions via the UserGroupPermission model. Users are tied to specific permissions via the UserPermission model.

**The end result** is to be able to call User.permissions and return every permission assigned to that user either directly or through a UserGroup.

Here is my current model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user_group

    #Permissions
    has_many :user_permissions
    has_many :user_group_permissions, :through => :user_group
    has_many :permissions, :through => :user_group_permissions #and :user_permissions
end
```

I've search high and low for a solution to this, but can't seem to find my exact case. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I've been told that is unclear what I'm asking. Hopefully this will help: Basically the User has_many :permissions, :through => :user_group_permissions and :user_permissions, but you can't use an and to join the results together. I'm trying to retrieve and combine the results of both of those relations into one.

**Edit 2:** I've been doing some work. This code gives the desired result, but I'm not sure how well it would work for potentially large databases.

```
  #Permissions
  has_many :user_permissions
  has_many :user_group_permissions, :through => :user_group
  #has_many :permissions, :through => :user_group_permissions
  #has_many :permissions, :through => :user_permissions

  def permissions
    all_permissions = []
    UserGroupPermission.where('user_group_id = ?', user_group_id).each do |ugp|
      all_permissions.append(Permission.find(ugp.permission_id))
    end

    UserPermission.where('user_id = ?', id).each do |p|
      all_permissions.append(Permission.find(p.permission_id))
    end

    return all_permissions
  end
```

Comment: I don't get you question? Can you explain what do you need?

Comment: @Misha Basically the User 
has_many :permissions, :through => :user_group_permissions and user_permissions

but you can't use an and to join the results together. I'm trying to retrieve and combine the results of both of those relations into one. I'll edit the post and try to be more clear.

Comment: Why don't you write a method named `all_permission` which gives you [user_permissions + permissions]?

Comment: @VasuAkeel Is the second edit's code along the lines of what you are suggesting?